# How can I predict data based on the dataset I have

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

I have a whole dataset containing 2000 students' scores the school from 7 parts, and if the 2000 students are willing to attend to the school.
[data examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKqjM.png)
Like this, if the scores are high, then it means the student loves this school, and I have a column at the end to show if the student is willing to attend the school(1 for yes and 0 for no).

I need to use these data to figure out which part of the score weights more, and I have another excel file with some scores, but I don't know if they are willing to attend to the school, I need to figure out that.

I already know that this would use some knowledge about machine learning, but currently I don't even know what I should learn to do that. So this is really a puzzle to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a very statistical point of view, without using machine learning, if you have this 7 scores from the students and a database with the answer, you can use average and median to check if there's a score that has is more representative to attend and to not attend so it can weigth more than others.

You can also try calculate the entropy of each score. You can calculate entropy with some libraries directly.

You can also dig a little bit about Binary Classification in Machine Learning. Classification refers to class, where we need to identify the object that by which class he belongs to. You already have the training data and so you will be able to create a model to apply to other data and predict if the student will attend or not.

Hope I have helped with the explanation.